# Change progressDialog font to custom on Android

Tags: android, android-styles, android-progressbar

What I'm trying to do is to change the font of progressBar message from default to custom.
I've already tried many techniques and failed.

I've tried to change it via Styles and then apply this style to my dialog:

```
<style name="StyledDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomStyle</item>
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf</item> // not working
</style>

<style name="CustomStyle">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf</item> // not working
</style>
```

Then I tried to get the message in TextView, but I'm getting null

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext(), R.style.StyledDialog); //tried with styles here.
dialog.create(); //yep, create the dialog, see that dialogs's onCreate method was executed;
TextView view = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message); // getting null
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        "fonts/epimodem.ttf");
view.setTypeface(face); //null pointerException
```

I'm using Calligraphy library to change the font of all the textViews I have.
So do you have any idea how to change the fond of the progressDialog I have

Comment: Did you try to create custom dialog?

Comment: @Alexey move TextView view = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message); after showing dialog. dialog.show(); after this find textview and will not be null

Comment: Are you using AlertDialog??

Comment: Please, take a look at this answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16045641/1533933 And try to change progress dialog message color/size first using spans (to ensure that there is no issue with font or something like this). After you succeed - try TypeFace span from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4826885/1533933 to use custom font.
Hope it helps

Comment: It worked, thanks. Consider posting an answer.

Comment: (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message); return null because you use R.id.message insteand of android.R.id.message

Comment: No, I've tried android.R.id.message, same null result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked like a charm:

```
 dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        String message = getContext().getString(R.string.building_route);
        SpannableString spannableString =  new SpannableString(message);

        CalligraphyTypefaceSpan typefaceSpan = new CalligraphyTypefaceSpan(TypefaceUtils.load(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf"));
        spannableString.setSpan(typefaceSpan, 0, message.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        dialog.setMessage(spannableString);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you and It is better to link the source. Need to add dependencies
dependencies {
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
}
Custom fonts in Android the easy way... 
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpannableString` without using stiles.xml

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.create();

SpannableString ss=  new SpannableString("Your message text here");
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/epimodem.ttf");
ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.0f), 0, ss.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", typeFace), 0, ss.length(), 0);

dialog.setMessage(ss);
dialog.show();
```

**CustomTypefaceSpan.java**

```
@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

    private final Typeface newType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
        super(family);
        newType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
    }

    private void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```